# Passing a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, react-props

Still learning Java and functions. Was writing some code but got stumped.

In my App.js class, I have a line of code in the return statement as follows:

```
<Toolbar drawerClickHandler ={props.drawerToggleClickHandler}/>
```

In my Toolbar class, it would activate via a "click" as follows:

```
<DrawerToggleButton click={props.drawerClickHandler}/>
```

Which would last be connected to another class DrawerToggleButton in the following code:

```
<button className="toggle-button" onClick={props.click}>
```

The Toolbas class and the DrawerToggleButton have no issues with passing but props.drawerToggleClickHandler does not work, says "Unresolved variable drawerToggleClickHandler".

How can I fix this? Full code below:

App.js:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
// import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Routes from "./Routes";
import { Auth } from "aws-amplify";
import { Link, withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
// import { Navbar } from "react-bootstrap";
import  Toolbar from './components/Toolbar/Toolbar';
import SideDrawer from './components/SideDrawer/SideDrawer';
import Backdrop from './components/Backdrop/Backdrop';


function App(props) {
  const [isAuthenticated, userHasAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [isAuthenticating, setIsAuthenticating] = useState(true);
  const [sideDrawerOpen, setIsSideDrawerOpen] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    onLoad();
  }, []);

  async function onLoad() {
    try {
      await Auth.currentSession();
      userHasAuthenticated(true);
    }
    catch(e) {
      if (e !== 'No current user') {
        alert(e);
      }
    }
    setIsAuthenticating(false);
  }

  function handleLogout() {
    userHasAuthenticated(false);
    props.history.push("/login");
  }

  function drawerToggleClickHandler(){
    if(sideDrawerOpen){
      return {setIsSideDrawerOpen: false};
    }
    else{
      return {setIsSideDrawerOpen: true};
    }

  }

  let sideDrawer;
  let backdrop;
  let toolBar;

  if(userHasAuthenticated === true){
    toolBar = <Toolbar drawerClickHandler ={props.drawerToggleClickHandler}/>
  }
  if (userHasAuthenticated === true && sideDrawerOpen === true){
    sideDrawer = <SideDrawer/>;
    backdrop = <Backdrop/>
  }
  return (
    <div className="App container" style={{height: '100%'}}>
      {toolBar}
      {sideDrawer}
      {backdrop}
      {/*<Toolbar/>*/}
      {/*<SideDrawer/>*/}
      {/*<Backdrop/>*/}
      <Routes appProps={{ isAuthenticated, userHasAuthenticated }} />
    </div>
  );
}

export default withRouter(App);
```

Toolbar.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './Toolbar.css';
import  DrawerToggleButton from '../SideDrawer/DrawerToggleButton'
import '../SideDrawer/DrawerToggleButton';
import sideDrawer from "../SideDrawer/SideDrawer";

const toolbar = props =>(
<header className="toolbar">
    <nav className="toolbar_navigation">
        <div>
            <DrawerToggleButton click={props.drawerClickHandler}/>
        </div>
        <div className="toolbar_logo"><a href="/">Kleen Portal</a></div>
        <div className="spacer" />
        <div className="toolbar_navigation-items">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Logout</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
</header>
);

export default toolbar;
```

DrawerToggleButton.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import './DrawerToggleButton.css'

const drawerToggleButton = props => (
  <button className="toggle-button" onClick={props.click}>
    <div className="toggle-button_line" />
    <div className="toggle-button_line" />
    <div className="toggle-button_line" />
  </button>
);

 export default drawerToggleButton;
```

Comment: This is not java. Java is very different from javascript. Please remove this tag.

Comment: There are no classes in your code. You use function components everywhere.

Comment: `const [sideDrawerOpen, setState] = useState(false);` should be `const [sideDrawerOpen, setSideDrawerOpen] = useState(false);`, and `return {sideDrawerOpen: false};` should be `setSideDrawerOpen(false);` (your current code is not changing state)

Comment: I'm building a codesandbox trying to find the error and you're apparently consistently using `useState` wrong. The pattern is `const [variable, setVariable] = useState(initialValue);`. To read the value, you simply do `if (variable === x)`; while `setVariable`, as the name implies, is a *function* used to change it. So in your code, `if (userHasAuthenticated === true)` checks whether a function that changes state is `true`, which obviously makes no sense.

Comment: Here's the working sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/trusting-darkness-e4tj3 (I also think that beginners are way better off using classes, as opposed to hooks. Learn standard React first, before diving into "cool kids' React")

Comment: Thanks so much Chris. Agree with you but I am stuck in a group (this is for a school project) and group mates are heading in this path. My last question is, I have another file in the project called Toolbar.js, code for it is stated above. In it I have <DrawerToggleButton click={props.drawerClickHandler}/> but it can not see drawerClickHandler. How can I get it to work?

Answer (score 1):

You're not changing state: you'd need to change your function to this (and i'd suggest renaming `setState` to `setsIsSideDrawerOpen`)

```
function drawerToggleClickHandler(){
  if(sideDrawerOpen){
    setState(false)
  }
  else{
    setState(true)
  }

}
```

Change

```
toolBar = <Toolbar drawerClickHandler ={props.drawerToggleClickHandler}/>
```

to

```
toolBar = <Toolbar drawerClickHandler ={drawerToggleClickHandler}/>
```

`drawerToggleClickHandler` is not a prop

[Also `app.js` is not a class it's a functional component]

to answer your second comment question I wouldn't event assign your component to a variable, just do it inline:

```
<div className="App container" style={{height: '100%'}}>
{userHasAuthenticated && <Toolbar drawerClickHandler =props.drawerToggleClickHandler}/>
  }
```

...

Comment: Thanks for the help. I fixed that. Still in the ToolBar.js, when I do:
<DrawerToggleButton click={props.drawerClickHandler}/>
it says "Unresolved variable drawerClickHandler"

Comment: Sorry, hit the enter button early, edited my comment above. Please take a look and thanks for the help.

Comment: Changed that but now it says that "Unresolved variable drawerToggleClickHandler" and that function drawerToggleClickHandler() is never used. This is all in App.js.

Comment: So I would have to convert App.js from functional component to a class and change all functions into methods or is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: no but perhaps you should ask a different question now that your code has changed because its hard to see your updated code

Comment: Did that but while everything is ok in App.js, Toolbar.js can not see drawerClickHandler

Comment: props.drawerToggleClickHandler throws an error and Toolbar.js still cant see drawerClickHandler

Comment: I think you need to read the react docs again so that you understand how prop passing works. It's kinda fundamental to learning react